Button combinations for different outputs
I'm a beginner and I'm currently trying to create an activity in Android Studio where if I click on a button, it will change the ImageView.
There are 6 buttons. 3 buttons of shape and 3 buttons of colour. From these 3 colours and 3 shapes, there would be 9 different combinations of colours and shapes so there are 9 different images.

SHAPE: Square, Triangle, Circle

COLOUR: Red, Blue, Green


How do I make it so that if I click on one shape button and one colour button, it will display an image based on that combination?
For example, if I click on Red and Square, it will display an image of a 'Red Square'? And after that, if I click on Green, the ImageView will display a 'Green Square'. Because I didn't click on another shape button, it didn't change the shape. In other words, the app still remembers that I clicked on Square before and stores that setting.
Thanks in advance! If my question is not clear please tell me!

What you want to achive is to restore the previous output when the app is restarted? But you don't know how to implement restoring using shared preferences? Confirm please.

I want to make it so that if I press a specific combination of buttons, I can get a specific output based on the combination. I'll edit the last part to make it more clear sorry.

I am afraid it is still unclear to me :( Have you sketched anything at all? Or you're still in zero. If the first one is true, let me see what you have tried so far.

so far I'm still at zero... sorry but i guess my question is still unclear :( i'll try to edit it again!

In your case you better see and study some tutorials on internet on how to use buttons, how to respond to button events etc. However, I will make a mini application that saves the last state in shared preferences so that you can study on it. Once it is done I'll post it in the answers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Start off by creating a new android studio project.
Add the following statement to the module level build.gradle file, into the android {} section so that you can use the ViewBinding feature.
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        // or for gradle in kotlin (kts) just add (=) sign
    }
}

Next, you define your colors in app->res->values->colors.xml file so that you can use them in your project. The colors.xml file should look something like the following.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
</resources>

Next, navigate to your activity's xml resource file and add the following xml. It is a simple structured layout just for demo purposes.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_circle_48" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clShape"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clColor">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvShape"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Select Shape"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.HeadlineSmall"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTriangle"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_triangle_48"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ibSquare"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ibCircle"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibSquare"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ibSquare" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibCircle"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_circle_48"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ibTriangle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibTriangle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ibTriangle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibSquare"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_square_48"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ibTriangle"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShape" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clColor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clShape"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvColor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Select Color"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.HeadlineSmall"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibRed"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_circle_48"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ibGreen"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvColor" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibBlue"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_circle_48"
            android:tint="#0000FF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ibGreen"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibGreen"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ibGreen" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibGreen"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_circle_48"
            android:tint="#00FF00"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ibRed"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ibBlue"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibRed"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ibRed" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

And last but not least, the acivity's java code.
package com.example.shapesandcolors;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.example.shapesandcolors.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String KEY_COLOR = "SP_KEY_COLOR";
    private static final String KEY_SHAPE = "SP_KEY_SHAPE";

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        // Setup views and related events
        // Listen to color change events
        binding.ibRed.setOnClickListener(v -> setOutputColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.red)));
        binding.ibBlue.setOnClickListener(v -> setOutputColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue)));
        binding.ibGreen.setOnClickListener(v -> setOutputColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.green)));
        // Also listen to shape change events
        binding.ibSquare.setOnClickListener(v -> setOutputShape(R.drawable.baseline_square_48));
        binding.ibTriangle.setOnClickListener(v -> setOutputShape(R.drawable.baseline_triangle_48));
        binding.ibCircle.setOnClickListener(v -> setOutputShape(R.drawable.baseline_circle_48));

        // Finally check shared preferences if there is something to restore
        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int color = sp.getInt(KEY_COLOR, -1);
        int shapeResId = sp.getInt(KEY_SHAPE, -1);
        // If there is no stored values then set defaults
        color = color == -1 ? ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.red) : color;
        shapeResId = shapeResId == -1 ? R.drawable.baseline_circle_48 : shapeResId;
        setOutputColor(color);
        setOutputShape(shapeResId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        binding = null;
    }

    // This method updates colors on image view and shape selection buttons
    private void setOutputColor(int color) {
        binding.imageView.setColorFilter(color);
        // If ou don't want the shape selection buttons to get tinted then remove the following 3 lines
        binding.ibCircle.setColorFilter(color);
        binding.ibTriangle.setColorFilter(color);
        binding.ibSquare.setColorFilter(color);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        spEditor.putInt(KEY_COLOR, color).apply();
    }

    // This method updates shape only on image view
    private void setOutputShape(int shapeResourceId) {
        binding.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), shapeResourceId));
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        spEditor.putInt(KEY_SHAPE, shapeResourceId).apply();
    }
}

If you setup everything correctly and launch your app, your should see an end result like in the following demo video.


I'll try it right away! Thank you so much! :)
